# Is there a way to redirect input from file to stdin in Netbeans?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I'm developing application with Netbeans and Maven. My application should obtain data from stdin. But I could not understand how to test it. Putting `< data.txt` into args list does not work.

I need the same as:

```
$ java MyProgram < data.txt
```

Comment: Why do you use stdin as input and not simply a paramenter which accesses a file?

Comment: @khmarbaise It is faster to write/read from parent to child process instead of:  open file/write to file/close file/run process/open file/read from file/close file. With my scenario I do not depend on filesystem performance and I could read from stream while parent process is writing to it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done by adding your own run target to your project's build.xml file. For example:

```
<target name="run" depends="jar">
  <exec dir="${work.dir}" executable="java" input="${work.dir}/inputfile.txt">
    <arg value="-jar"/>
    <arg file="${dist.jar}"/>
  </exec>
</target>
```

Note that commands such as Run, Debug, and Test only use your custom build.xml if the Compile on Save feature is turned off for the project. So you will need to ensure that Compile on Save is turned off in your project's properties.

Comment: I wonder why `Compile on Save` must be turned off to get this works?

Answer (score 11):

I assume you have a thing like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
...
}
```

This can used as an entry point to your application and before that you change the input channel via:

```
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("test.data"));
System.setIn(is);
```

The above can be used within a unit/integration test.

Comment: This is far convinient compared to @ZeroTau solution

Comment: But it will change the function of the code I afraid - i.e. the result program when run will read input from `test.data` file instead of the standard input stream.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how it is in NetBeans but in eclipse you can write something to console and it is redirected as STDIN to running application. I believe the same should work in NetBeans too. So, just run your application, then copy/paste content of `data.txt` to console and probably press `<ENTER>`.

If nothing help use remote debugging, i.e. run your program from command prompt as following:

`java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=y MyProgram < data.txt`

then connect to this process from NetBeans.

Comment: you are that one who understood my question. But unfortunately  such shell strig does not work in Netbeans :(

Answer (score 1):

Old school, but it's what I knew.  One caveat is that the mvn command does not return to the cli when done, but for some purposes this is acceptable.  Note you need to be in the project root directory

mvn "-Dexec.args=-classpath %classpath com.mycompany.test" -Dexec.executable=/Downloads/jdk1.7/bin/java exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec  < /tmp/Input

Answer (score 0):

Add a new target "run-input" under Files->build.xml with the following text. Note: this version uses the correct location of the java runtime. Also, it assumes that you have made a directory called inputs with the file input1.

```
<target name="run-input" depends="jar">
  <exec dir="${work.dir}" executable="${java.home}/bin/java" input="${src.dir}/inputs/input1">
    <arg value="-jar"/>
    <arg file="${dist.jar}"/>
  </exec>
</target>
```

You can always create a shortcut for this new target.