# Redirect standard input and output to text file when run/debug a Java project from Netbeans

Tags: debugging, netbeans, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I'm doing codegolf on codechef.com and using Netbeans IDE to write my code.

Since codechef site require the way to read/write from standard input/output, it is quite uncomfortable for me to run/debug the code to get the output; i.e. I have to entering the input manually.

The situation comes to critically imposiible with large input. And I need a way to turn  `System.in`/`System.out` to be some predefined input/output text file.

How can I do it in Java Netbeans?

I'm using Netbeans 7.3.1

Comment: Similar question here. It's already answered. [is there a way to redirect input from file to stdin in Netbeans?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686060/is-there-a-way-to-redirect-input-from-file-to-stdin-in-netbeans)

Comment: Please put your comment into an answer and brief us the solution so as I will choose it as accepted. Thank you!