# Console input lots of data for Java

Tags: java, netbeans, console, system.in

I wrote a program that accepts whitespace delimited numbers from console. For convenience, I saved all input in a file, such as:

```
1 4
3 5
3 4 5
1 2
1 1 -1
3 -1 0
2 0 -1
0 1 1
```

Normally, I run my program as:

```
    java -cp .:path  test
```

and then type the data above one by one on the console. I am tried of this. So is there any good way to run the test, so that it can takes the content in the file as console input?

Also, is it a good way in the netbean/eclipse for debug with these data? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can redirect the standard input to read from the file, like this:

`java -cp .:path  test < input.txt`

UPDATE:

I'm not familiar with Netbeans, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686060/is-there-a-way-to-redirect-input-from-file-to-stdin-in-netbeans) seems to answer your question

Comment: Thanks. And how to do it in the netbeas? I tried add ``< input.txt`` as arguments. but seems not work