# Netbeans Command line redirect

Tags: c, netbeans

In netbeans I need to use command line input redirect to make my program scanf a file.
my command line args look like

> "${OUTPUT_PATH}" < file.txt

file.txt has the word "Hello" in it

my code looks like:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char str[30];
    scanf("%s", str);
    printf("input: %s\n", str);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

When I run the program, it compiles fine, but doesn't read in the "Hello"; it appears to be looking for input eternally. This is C, not java

Comment: I suspect `scanf` is waiting for some kind of white-space to terminate the string. Make sure there's a newline character in your file at the end of Hello.

Comment: I have checked that, there is, but still no luck. I'm starting to wonder if maybe you can't do redirect in netbeans IDE

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  Amongst other things it is missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files.

Comment: regarding: `char str[30];
    scanf("%s", str);`  if the input is greater than 29 characters long (%s always appends a NUL byte to the input buffer) then the result will be a buffer overrun, resulting in undefined behavior.  the code should always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  Suggest: `char str[30];
    if( scanf("%29s", str) != 1) {fprintf( stderr, "scanf failed\n" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Comment: it does have the #includes i just forgot to put them in here. and the 30 is much larger than the 5 chars in hello

Comment: regarding: `int main(int argc, char** argv)`  this will cause the compiler to output two warning messages about unused parameters.  To fix this problem, suggest using the other valid signature for `main()`   `int main( void )`

Comment: what is the value of: `"${OUTPUT_PATH}"`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to redirect input from file to stdin in Netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686060/is-there-a-way-to-redirect-input-from-file-to-stdin-in-netbeans)